# check if entered value is same in multiple dynamic textboxes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textbox

I have a form with multiple dynamically generated textboxes. Say there are 5 textboxes with the same name and different ids.

I need to check that values entered in these text fields are unique ie;

Suppose:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox1" value="1">
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox1" value="2">
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox1" value="3">
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox1" value="4">
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox1" value="1">
```

In this case, an error must be shown the value is already entered. If values are distinct only the form can be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jquery.validationengine, but at least you can check it by hand, using

```
var valueX = ${'#textboxX'}.attr('value');
```

to read the `value` attribute of the input with index `X`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but it can help others so Check the solution

```
count = Number((document.frmDefineSSS.cboTeamSize.selectedIndex) - 1);
            flagSame = false;
            for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                for (j = i + 1; j <= count + 1; j++) {
                    if ($("#hidCommMemId" + [i]).val() == $("#hidCommMemId" + [j]).val()) {
                        alert("Team Member can't be same.");
                        $("#txtStudName" + [i]).css("background-color", "yellow");
                        $("#txtStudName" + [j]).css("background-color", "yellow");
                        flagSame = false;
                        return false;

                    }
                    else {
                        $("#txtStudName" + [i]).css("background-color", "white");
                        $("#txtStudName" + [j]).css("background-color", "white");
                        flagSame = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The following is other solution.

```
function findDuplicates() {
    var isDuplicate = false;
    jQuery("input[name^='access_keys']").each(function (i,el1) {
        var current_val = jQuery(el1).val();
        if (current_val != "") {
            jQuery("input[name^='access_keys']").each(function (i,el2) {
                if (jQuery(el2).val() == current_val && jQuery(el1).attr("name") != jQuery(el2).attr("name")) {
                    isDuplicate = true;
                    jQuery(el2).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    jQuery(el1).css("background-color", "yellow");
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    if (isDuplicate) {
        alert ("Duplicate values found.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I basically loop through all the text boxes and compare the values with all the other textboxes, in nested loops. Basically it is like bubble sort. I know this is bad, but was not able to think of any efficient way of doing it. Do you guys can think of a better way?